# Hide/shaded a react navigation screen header while function is loading

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to make a custom loading screen while my Firebase function is updating the data and avoid the user to leave the screen while loading, except that my header is still clickable and doesn't prevent the user to go back.

I tried with SafeAeraView, etc. but I didn't get any result.

The research goal illustrated:

[Here is a pic of what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RPgf.png)

This is how I do it:

```
    if (taked === true) {        
        setTimeout(() => {
            cancelDelivery();
        }, 1500);      
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "grey",justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={require('../../assets/images/delivraide-icon-192.png')}/>
                <Text style={styles.patientText}>Veuillez patientez s'il vous plaît</Text>
            </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          );
```

After the function is executed, the user is returned to the parent with the PopToTop function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is prevent default behavior while you are updating data by adding a listener on `beforeRemove` event (please check [this doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/) to know when this event is triggered). You will need to have some state variable (`updatingData` or whatever) and set it to `true` when you start the request and set it to `false` when request completes.

```
navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
  if (updatingData) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```